# Why path prefix is always leading to en instead of User's preferred language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, transliteration

I am working a multi-lingual website which has 9 languages enabled. But the issue I am facing is irrespective of user's preferred language, site will be always prefixed with `en`. The required behaviour should be when `chinese` preferred language user logged in, it should be prefixed with `https://example.com/zh-hans`. Below are the Language detection combinations I tried:

[image]

[image]

I tried with [User Account Language Negotiation](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_account_language_negotiation)  module also. But no success. Can anyone help me in this regard.